# Is it allowed to be friends with a muslim Jinn?

Tags: jinn, relationships

I'm really interested in Jinn (how they're made of fire and stuff, I love science), but I'm also religious so I don't have any intention of asking favors or anything, just to talk and be friends. It would be nice to interact with another intelligent species. I preferably want to communicate with a Muslim jinn, if there's any way to find one?

Comment: Interaction between humans and jinns is explicitly prohibited. No practicing Muslim human or Muslim jinn will interact with each other. They fear Allah and are aware of the limits set by their Lord.

Comment: Jinn's are not intelligent , at least as much as humans. Jinns were blessed by strength of the body by Allah and Humans are blessed with intellect of the mind.  Ever wondered why Jinns hate humans  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Qur'an tells us that there are indeed some Jinn's that are believers. But I wonder if we can even meet Jinn and contact them first to be able to find a Muslim one. This sounds weird and rather unrealistic. The Qur'an in fact tells as the origin of Jinn and that they are with or around us, but there's no clue in it on how one might be able to contact them. Nevertheless believers among them may like to listen to a Qur'an recitation. But do we have any certainty about their real intention? ... the Qur'an in fact seems to show us that we can hardly trust them as they know as better than we know them, they can see us while we can't and maybe there are hypocrites among them -assuming they are similar to us in matter of belief-.

Based on the quran verse and more explicitly on the marked part:

> O children of Adam, let not Satan tempt you as he removed your parents from Paradise, stripping them of their clothing to show them their private parts. **Indeed, he sees you, he and his tribe, from where you do not see them**. Indeed, We have made the devils allies to those who do not believe. ([7:27](https://legacy.quran.com/7/27))

Sheikh ibn Bazz concluded in [this is fatwa](https://binbaz.org.sa/fatwas/18363/%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85-%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%82%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%86) -in Arabic- that one is not allowed to be friends with Jinn due to the simple fact that one cannot trust them, they might pretend being Muslims for example, and that the general case is that we are not able to see them. Nevertheless it is allowed to ask Allah to guide them etc. but one shouldn't fully trust them.

Allah also says:

> And among us are the righteous, and among us are [others] not so; we were [of] divided ways. ([72:11](https://legacy.quran.com/72/11))

Which has been taken as a basis to allow such a friendship if it leads to good (their guidance or to use them for good deeds etc.) in this fatwa on islamweb #[35055](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=35055)-in Arabic-.

Comment: Hmm guess I have to resort to kidnapping a bad Jinn then. It's just too tempting to study their biology.

Comment: Jazzak Allahu Khair. The provided link of Islamweb is no longer valid. Can you kindly update the link? Are you talking about [this](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/index.php?page=fatwaadvancedsearch&Word=35055&Option=QuestionId&R1=0&R2=0) QA of Islamweb?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we ask for things that are not meant for us, but just because we ask too much for it ALLAH GRANTS it and then we realise that what is good for us would surely come FROM LORD and it woulds be much better than what we want for our selves. Sometimes one gets into jinns and it takes them years and years of torment and disturbances of various sorts, then to come out of thier clutches, that is after you pray TO ALLAH to get you rid of them. You would see faces changing and coming close to you when you close your eyes to sleep, myriad dreams that you don't want, they can get into your Central thought system and mess with it big time, so much so that you would get thoughts that you think are your own but are not, and these can be bad thoughts about your Deen, astagfirullah. There is no saying which jinn is momin or not and they could pretend to be momin, simply because through you they get peace, just like you get peace with another good momin, but the thing is that non momin jinns can mess with that peace big time and invite more and more non momin jinns to create havoc in your life. Give you strange sharp pains and aches, and not only you but people who are around you, to the point that people stop meeting you, because they feel unusual activity when you are around, it could destroy your business and family life too. What would a momin jinn want from you, he has ALLAH. But chances are if you are desperately looking for jinns you might invite some non momin jinns and your troubles will start from them on. Ultimately you will be scared, bewildered, because of non stop excessive thinking that is not your own and you don't know where it is coming from, you will be empty of energy and will notice that your happiness is gone because the moment you think of doing something good it well be interrupted with another thought, put in by the jinn and that thought of yours will be gone till you hunt for it and then the mood is gone. This will keep repeating till you are totally fed up and by then you have already opened your mind to them and they want the best of you till you have nothing left for your self. 
ask ALLAH TO GIVE you what HE KNOWS is good for you and not what you think is good for you. Bad jinns means bad bodily pains, bad thoughts and bad vibes. Good jinns have thier own good things to do. Best wishes, may ALLAH SUBHAAN AW TAALA MOST MERCIFUL MOST KIND KEEP you and your loved ones safe and happy always and always ameen summa ameen IN SHAA ALLAH HU TAALA.

Answer (score -1):

If you want friendship with muslim jinn then recite surah jinn every day along with surah baqarah at home. Then do tahajud and ask Allah.. you should do it more than 3 months. And see the results

Comment: Where is the source